# how to append or update JSON datatype value in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, php, postgresql-9.3

hey guys i'm using PHP's codeigniter to create my application and postgreSQL as database and i have to update some value in database.
So, let's say we have table structure like this:-

```
CREATE TABLE emailrecord (
   id serial NOT NULL,
   email json 
);
```

insert first record

```
INSERT INTO emailrecord (email) VALUES('{"id":"abc@any.com"}');
```

Now, how to update the inserted record at 1 which is to be like this

```
'{{"id":"abc@any.com"},{"id","def@any.com"}}'
```

AND

is there any way to update it via `CODEIGNITER`  it would be helpful for me

Comment: Why are you using JSON for this field?

Comment: because it is just a example but i have to add many key  value pair in it, different keys and different values

Comment: IMO, you should be putting each unique email in separate rows and you are duplicating id twice, when you use json, if you still want multiple values array is a better approach. OTH unique values will make updating/deleting easier. and just a thought json (in this case) will also increase your "autovaccum overheads".